# Different languages for different users in Debian Stretch with Xfce

Tags: debian, xfce, language

I have a Debian Stretch system running Xfce in Spanish. I want to set a specific user's CLI and interface to English, without affecting everyone else's. How do I achieve this? I've read multiple threads on the topic but none of the suggested solutions seemed to work. Thanks.

Comment: Will you only need to change the language in menus and applications or will the keyboard layouts need to be different as well?

Comment: Keyboard layout will be the same

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a .Xsession file in the home specific user's :

```
cat .Xsession 
export LC_ALL=us_US.utf8
startxfce4
```

It's not perfect so you can try to ask [here](https://forum.xfce.org/index.php)